# dataproc custom image with REST api or Java API

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc

Can we create a dataproc cluster with custom image using Rest API or Java API. what config parameter can be used to give custom image name/uri. According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/reference/rest/v1beta2/ClusterConfig#instancegroupconfig), ImageURI in instanceGroupConfig is "Output only. The Compute Engine image resource used for cluster instances. Inferred from **SoftwareConfig.image_version**."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Output Only] tag on `instanceGroupConfig.imageUri` field is a hold over from when it was [Output Only]. As long as you set imageUri for both Master and Worker groups the setting will be honored.

In the mean time we will change the documentation.